# how to change font size of a title of a select list in jquery-mobile?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

hi i would like to change the font of the title but i tried many things like put a `style="font-size:11px;"`, in the label but it didn t work, i edit the select class but didn t work too (i tried to add !important too)...
i m sure there is an easy way but i don t find it... Actualy this text is using H1 style but i can t edit it ... a picture to understand (i don t want to change options font). thx for help and sorry for my bad english

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=858604Capture.png

```
            <form name="fromListMedecins">
            <label class="select" for="select_list_medecins">choisissez une spécialité :</label>
                <select name="select_list_medecins" id="select_list_medecins" data-icon="tag" data-iconpos="left" data-native-menu="false">
                    <option value="1" selected="">Médecine générale (par défaut)</option>
                    <option value="2" selected="">Médecine 2 </option>
                    <option value="3" selected="">Médecine 3</option>                       
            </select>
        </form>
```

Comment: Can you add slightly more complete code? At present, using your HTML with jQuery Mobile CSS and JavaScript does not yield the same appearance as your attached image. http://jsfiddle.net/AzjHk/

Comment: sry, 
the css class for the title used is `.ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title { text-align:center; overflow:visible; padding-top:0.7em; padding-right:0px; font-size:1.5em; display:block; white-space:nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis; min-height:1.1em; outline-width:0px !important; outline-style:none !important; outline-color invert !important; }` someone maybe alter the css, but i don t want to alter it again ... (options are differents because i add them with javascritp)

Comment: the list doesn t work, but i don t care i just want to change the font of "choisissez une spécialité" http://jsfiddle.net/AzjHk/

Comment: i made a mistake their the good jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/AzjHk/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is your updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/AzjHk/1/)**

All I did is add a font-size rule to your .select class with a !important:

```
.select {
    font-size: 11px !important;
}
```

!important makes sure this rule overrides the build in jQM rules.

Comment: sry i failed to give u the jsfield 
http://jsfiddle.net/AzjHk/4/ there is the good, ps i don t want to alter the class ui-title, i fixed the vue, i add the jquery mobile, don t know if it s usefull ... the first and the sird select show the problem, the 4th it s what appear on click in my application ...

Comment: i changed `.ui-header .ui-title, ui-footer .ui-title {
    font-size: 1em;   
}`
and looks like it wasn t used in other place so it s fine now thx for help anyway